# Assign value in tuple returned from Python keyword to variable

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a Python keyword returning a tuple. I just need to assign the first value of the tuple.

Is there a better way than this?

```
${tuple_to_list} =    Keyword returning a tuple    ${arg0}    ${arg1}   
${first_element} =    Get From List    ${tuple_to_list}    0
```

Comment: Are you trying to unpack a tuple? Then you can just do a, b = tuple

Comment: Doing that would still force me to create an unused variable. Maybe better than creating a list and then having to do a Get From List?

Comment: Generally if you unpack a variable you don't need you just write a, _ = tuple. I don't care having unused variables. Why don't wont you have unused variables?

Comment: Could you show us an executable code snippet of your current scenario? Right now it's kinda hard to understand what you have and what you want... If you want just the first value, than you could do a a = your_tuple[0]

Comment: @PedroMartinsdeSouza In RF a tuple returned from Python becomes a list. What you suggest is exactly what my lines of code do, that is assign the Python tuple to a RF list and getting the first element of the list.

Comment: @kabooya I don't care too, but if there was a way to avoid the unused variable it would be better.

Comment: So what's wrong with your current approach, it's good enough?

Comment: @TodorMinakov I assigned both values from the tuple to two different variables, even if the second will be unused. After all I think it's better to have an unused variable than creating a list and getting the first element.

Comment: An unused variable is not that much of a bad thing - if the actual value exists (like in a tuple/list members), in python the variable is nothing more than an identifier to that value; 
e.g. "one more label to the same memory address. You don't waste memory or cpu, just have one more string in your namespace. I'm oversimplifying, but this is what happens in short. And your keyword/method already created the list with all its members - e.g. reserved the memory needed for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing for sequences like strings, lists and tuples in Python.
You can find information on slicing with a quick web search or here: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html

Here is a quick example:

```
# Create a tuple of 3 items
my_tuple = (2, 4, 6)
# Tuples are indexed starting at 0.
# The syntax to retrieve s single item is tuple[index]
first_item = my_tuple[0]
print(first_item)
```

Comment: I can't change the Python keyword source.

Comment: So, you are receiving a keyword argument as a tuple?  let's call that keyword kwarg1.  In such a case, the first item of the kwarg1 tuple is is kwarg1[0].    If I'm missing something, please clarify or show an executable code snippet.

Comment: Not a keyword argument, but the keyword's return value is a tuple, which for RF is a list. So there is no other way than let RF "listify" the tuple and then accessing the first item?